# Errors “Page expired” when upload project Laravel to Shared hosting (Cpanel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a problem after Uploading my Laravel project to shared hosting. Everything is ok when I test by Xampp(Localhost). But in production on shared hosting, I click "Submit button" on every Form-> It appears: `Page Expired. Although I have `Csrf_token` and have searched many questions about my problem, I cannot resolve it. Please help me!!!

**This is my form:**

```php
<form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nrp">NRP</label>
        <input class="form-control @error('nrp') is-invalid @enderror" type="number" name="nrp" id="nrp" autofocus required>
        @error('nrp')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>NRP / Password yang dimasukan salah!</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
        @error('password')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
            
    <div class="d-flex mb-5 mt-2 align-items-center">
        <label class="control control--checkbox mb-0">
            <span class="caption">Remember me</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" />
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
        </label>
        <span class="ml-auto">
            <a href="{{ route('user.register') }}" class="forgot-pass">Register Account</a>
        </span> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
</form>
```

**The Route:**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

I'm using `laravel/ui` for auth.

Please check the website for the example of the error http://etwpad.id/login

Comment: What SESSION_DRIVER are you using and do you have your APP_URL set correctly?

Comment: SESSION_DRIVER = file , and APP_URL is https://etwpad.id

Comment: @AlghanyJagad does it works in you local ?

Comment: Is your directory `/storage/framework/sessions` writable?

Comment: how do i know it is writable or not?

Comment: @KamleshPaul it is work on my local

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an application key.

Run `php artisan key:generate`. This will create a key and place it in your `.env` file (`APP_KEY`).

Then `php artisan config:cache`. This will clear you cache for use of the new key.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to add
`ob_start();`
at the beginning of the index.php file in the root folder or public/index.php